# How can i activate paging buttons on flexigrid?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, flexigrid

I have a flexigrid table when 20 items, i need to be able to use the paging buttons to change the page of the flexigrid, but when i click them nothing happens, in the other hand, the refresh button of the flexigrid works. Here is my code:

```
$(".flexArticle").flexigrid({
                    url: "index.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    colModel : [
                        {display: 'ID', name : 'id', width : 40, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                        {display: 'Nombre', name : 'name', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                        {display: 'Categoria', name : 'category', width : 150, sortable : true, align: 'left'}
                    ],
                    searchitems : [
                        {display: 'Nombre', name : 'name'}
                    ],
                    sortname: "id",
                    sortorder: "asc",
                    usepager: true,
                    title: "Articulos",
                    useRp: true,
                    rp: 10,
                    showTableToggleBtn: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    width: 'auto',
                    height: 'auto',
                    singleSelect: true,
                });
```

What am i missing to achieve the paging?

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement paging at the ServerSide also and get the values of paging indexes from there.

Flexigrid requires a few parameters to be passed back in the JSON array.

**Page**: The current page number.

**Total**:The total number of records in the result set. Used by Flexigrid to calculate the number of pages

**Rows**: This is an array containing the data for the rows. Each row needs a unique id and an array of column data.